# Deleting a application server from WAS liberty

Tags: websphere-liberty

I have a basic question and did google but could not find the answer for this

For example I create a application server on WAS liberty

```
example :  bin/server create simpleServer
```

How can I delete this 'entry' from WAS liberty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to remove the server make sure it is stopped and then go to usr/servers/ and delete the folder. The folder name will be that of your server.

Comment: Thank you.  I was thinking about 'deletion' but I thought there would be some other mechanism to delete

Comment: @SathishKumar, If this answer helped you, please mark as Answered.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'delete' function for Liberty's server command. This is because all of the files created during the 'create' step are contained in the resulting server directory.

As mentioned in other posts to delete a server simply rm -rf it!